Ex. 8.21 in Einseidler & Ward FA book: where do we need that $G$ is abelian?
I am working through the following exercise in Einsiedler & Ward's book Functional Analysis, Spectral Theory, and Applications.

Exercise 8.21: Let $G$ be a compact metric abelian group. Show that there exists a $G$-invariant positive linear functional $\Lambda : C_{\mathbf{R}}(G) \to \mathbf{R}$ with $\Lambda(\mathbf{1}_G) = 1$, and deduce the existence of a Haar measure on $G$.

Following the prompt in the book's hints, I have come up with following proof which I sketch below:
Proof Outline:

Step 1: Since $G$ is compact metric, $C(G)$ is separable, so if $\mathbf{B} = \{\ell \in C(G)^\ast : \|\ell\| \leq 1\}$ is the norm-closed unit ball of $C(G)$'s dual, we have that $\mathbf{B}$'s weak* topology is metrizable.

Step 2: For any fixed $g \in G$, we let $X_g$ be the set of positive, $g$-invariant linear functionals of norm $1$. We can show that $X_g$ is a weak* closed subspace of $\mathbf{B}$, so if we can show that $\mathscr{X} = \{X_g : g\in G\}$ has the finite intersection property, we will be done.

Step 3: To show that each $X_g$ is nonempty, we take any positive linear functional $L$ of norm 1 on $C(G)$, and set:
$$L_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} L \circ \phi_g^j$$
where $\phi_g(f) = f(g-)$ is precomposition by left multiplication by $g$. Since $(L_n)$ is inside of $\mathbf{B}$, then there is some subsequence $(L_{n_k})$ and $L' \in \mathbf{B}$ so that $L_{n_k} \to L'$ in weak*, and one can show that $L'$ is positive, $g$-invariant, and norm 1.

Step 4: We can then repeat this construction for finitely many $g$ to show that for every $g_1,\dots,g_n \in G$, the intersection $\bigcap_{i=1}^n X_g$ is nonempty, which by compactness of $\mathbf{B}$ shows that $\bigcap_{g \in G} X_g$ is nonempty.

Step 5: We can apply the Riesz representation theorem to any $\Lambda \in \bigcap_{g \in G} X_g$ to produce a Haar measure, finishing the proof. $\blacksquare$



In the exercise we assume that $G$ is abelian, but I can't figure out any place in the proof where that is needed, other than justifying the absence of "left" or "right" modifying the Haar measure.
The only place that I could imagine that we need elements of $G$ to commute is in Step 4, but the argument I have is by induction: we assume that there is some $\Lambda$ which is invariant under $g_1,\dots,g_{n-1}$, and then take $\Lambda$ to be $L$ in Step 3. This clearly doesn't demand any commutativity, and the resulting weak* subsequential limit is invariant under each of $g_1,\dots,g_n$ as desired.
Here is my question: Am I correct in thinking that the only reason we assume that $G$ is abelian is so that the resulting Haar measure is two-sided? Or am I missing something?

In Step 4, I guess what you mean is to take $\ell\in \bigcap_{j=1}^n X_{g_j}$ and apply Step 3 with $g=g_{n+1}$. If that's what you do, the problem is to ensure is that the resulting functional is still invariant under $g_1,\dots,g_n$.

Ah! I can’t believe I missed that. If you want, you can write this as an answer and I’ll accept it. Thank you!

In Step 4, if you $\ell\in\bigcap_{j=1}^n X_{g_j}$ and apply Step 3 with $g=g_{n+1}$, you get a functional that is invariant under $g_{n+1}$. What is not clear (and not true in general) is that the resulting functional is still invariant under $g_1,\dots,g_n$. If the group is abelian, then the $\phi_{g_{n+1}}$ and $\phi_{g_j}$ commute, which implies that the approximating functionals in Step 3 are still invariant under $g_1,\dots,g_n$ and so is any weak$^\ast$ limit point.
This fixed point argument is a special case of the Markov-Kakutani fixed-point theorem, which can be proven essentially in the same way as sketched in the question.

I hadn't heard of this theorem before, so thanks for pointing that out!
